# Callback function with Mxnet in C++

Tags: c++, callback, mxnet

With Mxnet, it is possible to use callback functions. One perfect example is with the R API - [How to save a model when using MXnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517960/how-to-save-a-model-when-using-mxnet#44194894).

But with the C++ API, I don't find any example on how to use them, nor some default callback functions (such as the one to save the weights). Though, by  searching "callback", I do have some hits, such as "MXExecutorSetMonitorCallback" or "ExecutorMonitorCallback".

How to define and use callback functions in C++?